# Export to Excel Formatting

Tags: .net, excel, datagrid

I have set up a basic html table with a reader in each cell (don't ask) that exports to excel, I also have a datagrid that exports to excel.  Both work without issue in regards to actually creating the spreadsheet, but I have a question regarding formatting.  Inside each cell is a list of names, i.e.:

Bob Smith     Jim Bob
John Miller   Susie Q
Jane Doe

When the spreadsheet comes up it places each name in a separate "sub cell" instead of having it all in one cell.  Is there a way I can make it so that the names in each html table cell are in a single Excel cell?

Comment: what does your HTML look like?

Comment: <table>
  <tr>
    <td><repeater>name 1<br />name 2<br /></repeater></td>
    <td><repeater>name 3<br />name 4<br /></repeater></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><repeater>name 1<br />name 2<br /></repeater></td>
    <td><repeater>name 3<br />name 4<br /></repeater></td>
  </tr>
</table>

When in excel it comes out with a border around names 1 and 2, but they are in separate sub cells of the border.  So in order to add another name in Excel an entire row has to be added instead of just typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the `<br>` which is creating the sub-cells.  Try putting "& chr(13)" or "& vbCrLf" or even "\r\n" instead.

Excel is a complete crapshoot when it comes to formatting stuff.  So, I often avoid the headache of exporting directly to excel and providing a view of the report which is copy and pastable into excel instead.

For example, I had a report which my users could click a button to view in 3 different ways:

1. A YUI enhanced html table with sorting, column resizing etc.  (Great for browser but tricky to paste properly into excel)
2. A simple HTML table which the users could copy and paste into excel very easily.  With an html table each `<TD>` corresponds to a cell and `<tr>` is a row.
3. A CSV view which could also be pasted into excel or into notepad.

All i did was write a format method which I could pass in as parameters what the header prefix/suffix, row prefix/suffix, col prefix/suffix, and table prefix/suffix.  I'd pass the appropriate params into the format method based on a GET param.

Answer (score 2):

You could try surrounding them with quotes, e.g. "Bob Smith".

Comment: Meaning the all names in a cell?  So header of the repeater having " and footer "?